# Validating a form with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to validate a form using a JavaScript function. I think it works, but the output disappears almost immediately.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<form name="myForm">
    Your Age: <input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit" value=" Send " id="submit">
</form>



document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate () {

    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;

    if (x > 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congrats you have entered x, your answer has been submitted";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR: Please enter a valid age";
        return false;
    }

}
```

What ya think boys?

Comment: "Boys?" If the output is disappearing I would guess the form submit is going ahead, causing the page to reload. Have you looked at `event.preventDefault()`? Also, it's generally better to validate in response to the form element's `submit` event rather than a button click.

Comment: "stops the default event of an element from happening" Isn't that what the return false; is for? Or that's what this guy on the tutorial i'm watching said.

Comment: Is it still disappearing when you enter a not valid age?

Comment: yes, for instance if i input a string it replies, ERROR please enter a valid age and then dissapears

Comment: `return false` doesn't work from within an event handler bound with `addEventListener()`. (It does work from event handlers bound via older techniques, but those are generally frowned upon these days. Stick with `.addEventListener()` and use `event.preventDefault()`.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the default behaviour by getting the `event` argument in `validate` function and use `.preventDefault();` to prevent default behaviour.

Then if the condition satisfies, submit the form via JavaScript using `submit()` function.
For that, either add the `action` and `method` or use ajax.

```js
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", validate);

function validate (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;

    if (x > 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Congrats you have entered x, your answer has been submitted";
        //submit your form here by using formelement.submit();
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "ERROR: Please enter a valid age";
        return false;
    }

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
    Your Age: <input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit" value=" Send " id="submit">
</form>
<div id="demo"></div>
```